# Javascript in Footer Not Loading in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code for hiding and showing a navigation bar on my Wordpress website:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $("#pn-navigation-bar").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#pn-navigation-bar").fadeOut();
    }
});


var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("pn-navigation-bar").style.opacity = 0;
        document.getElementsByClassName("readingProgressbar")[0].style.display = "block";
    } else if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("pn-navigation-bar").style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementsByClassName("readingProgressbar")[0].style.display = "none";

    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};
```

And the following CSS to prevent it from loading the first time the page loads:

```
#pn-navigation-bar {
     position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 display: none;
}
```

Ideally, this should be hiding the Navigation bar shown below while the user scrolls down and show it when a scroll up is detected.

[image]

However, as you can see if you visit the website [here](https://theyellipages.in), this does not happen. This was working fine till a few days ago, but I don't know what has gone wrong. I've been optimizing my website for speed (JS/CSS minification) but I doubt that this gets affected. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You have console. errors. The script cannot find $ - you likely need to move jQuery to the top of the head

Comment: I've now added the script in the `<head>` section, but to no avail. Why did this suddenly stop working though? Did I mess around with something by accident?

Comment: You need the ***jQuery*** library code earlier in the head

Comment: `<head>
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>` Do you mean this? I'm sorry, I'm not very fluent with all this :/

Comment: Yes, but then remove the `<script type="bf4ef72ae5b10140c7328f26-text/javascript" src='https://theyellipages.in/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp' id='jquery-core-js'></script>`

Comment: which by the way has a type that looks suspicious

Comment: @mplungjan Unless I'm mistaken, it'll be hard to locate that piece of HTML in a WP installation.

Comment: @AmanBhargava - but necessary

Comment: WordPress uses jQuery.noConflict ... You must define $.

Comment: @mplungjan Fixed it by mapping jQuery to $

Comment: Ok. https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! Although do you have any idea why this happened all of a sudden? I'm confused whether JS minification has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by users @mplungjan and @Howard E, Wordpress runs jQuery.noConflict. To prevent conflict with other JS librares, Wordpress will not recognize `$` to be JQuery code and usually expects `Jquery` in place of the traditional `$`

To fix this, the easiest way is to map `$` to `JQuery`.

According to [this article](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/), The code for this is:

```
(function($) {
    
//Insert Code Here
    
})( jQuery );
```

To correct the error, the code becomes:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $("#pn-navigation-bar").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#pn-navigation-bar").fadeOut();
    }
});


var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("pn-navigation-bar").style.opacity = 0;
        document.getElementsByClassName("readingProgressbar")[0].style.display = "block";
    } else if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("pn-navigation-bar").style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementsByClassName("readingProgressbar")[0].style.display = "none";

    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};  
})( jQuery );
</script>
```